# Docker file is wrong ! Error : Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I am getting following error:

"Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file."

While try to build the image and getting the shown in the image

[image]

Following image shows my docker commands.

Also the images shows the code which i am trying to build. It shows the structure of the code which is src folder and a solution file outside the src folder.

I strongly belive issue is solution file is not in src.

[image]

Please recommend what will be change in docker files to make a successfull build and push.

I also showing the deployment.yaml file which shows the steps of the build below image

```
    name: test run 
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-abc'
      azureContainerRegistry:
      loginServer: acr.azurecr.io
      id: "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/eus-abc-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acr"
      imageName: acr.azurecr.io/ims-abc/dotnetapi:jp26052022v8
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: Push an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-abc'
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"acr.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/eus-icndp-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acr"}'
      action: Push an image
```

Comment: Try to move `WORKDIR /app` before the `Copy . .` in Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks it worked but i am getting error An image does not exist locally with the tag: icndpaksacr.azurecr.io/autopipe
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: acr.azurecr.io/ims-abc/dotnetapi:jp26052022v8

Comment: i was thinking image will be created automatically, but looks like the image will be updated only

Comment: do i need to create a image there in that name then what should be image name?

Comment: Yes, you need to push an existing image, which means the image need to be created firstly. Please check [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#build-and-push) for your reference.

Comment: i am creating image name dynamically, so how is it possible

Comment: You have specified image name in the build task in yaml. But if you create the image name dynamically, please give a try with `buildAndPush` for [Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#build-and-push) task without tag info. You can create a new ticket for this topic for better tracking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541896/erroran-image-does-not-exist-locally-with-the-tag-icndpaksacr-azurecr-io-au

Comment: Please have a look and comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move `WORKDIR /APP` before `COPY . .` so that in the directory, it can find the solution file.

You need to create the image in pipeline, then can publish the image to ACR. Please check [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#build-and-push) for your reference.