# ##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: icndpaksacr.azurecr.io/autopipe

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I am getting error while i push image through azure pipeline

```
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: icndpaksacr.azurecr.io/autopipe
```

[image]

I am using the following deployment file

```
name: test run 
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-abc'
      azureContainerRegistry:
      loginServer: acr.azurecr.io
      id: "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/eus-abc-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acr"
      imageName: acr.azurecr.io/ims-abc/$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: Push an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-abc'
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"acr.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/eus-icndp-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acr"}'
      action: Push an image
```

As it says image is not exists in registry, however, i am creating image dynamically $(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)  , it will not possible to keep the image in repository upfront, how to go about this?

Comment: Try to add a task before Docker push, to list the current image for confirmation(docker image ls). Meanwhile, you are using `Docker@0`, please change to use latest `Docker@2` task.

Comment: ok, can you forward me the sample task , how to create a dummy image in same name should look like?

Comment: as per my understanding a image in the same name should exist in registry before i build and push image in the same name..correct?

Comment: Thanks issue is fixed when i changed to Docker@2 , please post that as answer, i will accept.. thanks a lot!

Comment: But i am getting this errro now ##[error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: Before you push the image, add a new  `Docker@2` task with `login` argument to authenticate the ACR.

Comment: can you provide me a sample of task with login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm the images before Docker push with a new task:
`- script: docker image ls`.

And Suggest to use latest `Docker@2` task instead of `Docker@0`.

Before you push the image, make sure you have authenticated, you can add below task:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
```

Comment: I am able to push it and got success message, but unable to find this in aks registry

Comment: Successfully tagged autopipe:178
Finishing: Build & Push image to $(container.registry) container registry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543868/unable-to-find-the-pushed-image-in-the-azure-container-registry please comment here