# Unable to find the pushed image in the azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I have pushed a new image in the azure container registry

[image]

But i am unable to find the image in azure container registry
[image]

Please find the deplyment yaml file

```
name: Dotnet Code Build and Push
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: Docker@0
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-***dp'
      azureContainerRegistry:
      loginServer: *****aksacr.azurecr.io
      id: "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-b87bf**747ff/resourceGroups/eus-***dp-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/*****aksacr"
      imageName: ***dpacr.azurecr.io/ims-***dp/$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Login to ACR
    inputs:
      command: login
      containerRegistry:'sc-***dp'
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Push an image
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'sc-***dp'
      repository: ims-***dp
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"*****aksacr.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/4f76bb2f-c521-45d1-b311-b87bf**747ff/resourceGroups/eus-***dp-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/*****aksacr"}'
      action: Push an image
```

Comment: Could you share the push code on Azure Devops pipeline?

Comment: update the question with push yaml file

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create a new service connection with the container registry if one does not exist.

[image]

and select Azure Container Registry.

[image]

Then you can push in your registry using the below task. Keep in mind that `${{container}}` should have a notation as **`xxx.azurecr.io/imagename:tag`**

```
 - task: Docker@2
    displayName: pushing image ${{container}} 
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'serviceConnectionName'
      repository: '${{container}}'
      command: 'push'
      tags: |
        mytag
```

Comment: I already have a service connection with the same steps , this is the name of service connection "sc-***dp"

Comment: i tried this   - task: Docker@2
    displayName: pushing image ${{container}} 
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'sc-icndp'
      repository: '${{container}}'
      command: 'push'
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildId)

Comment: But still i cant see image

Answer (score 1):

**Try to push the code in azure devops pipeline so you can directly push image in azure container registry**

Here we can docker task it can build up and push the image with help of setting and it take the image from repository and then it can push into the azure container registry

```yaml
 task: Docker@2
    displayName: Push an image
    inputs:
      command: buildAndpush
       repository: $(imageRepository)
       dockerfile: $(dockerfilepath)
           ContainerRegistry: $(dockerRepositoryserviceconnectio)
           tags:
               $(tag)
```

Save and run.

[image]

**Note** : *After running you can't see Repository please refresh again  because in azure pipeline the job may be still running  once the job is completed & successfully run and refresh you can able see image is pushed*

Please refer this [document](https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2022/02/13/building-and-pushing-docker-images-to-azure-container-registry-with-azure-devops-pipelines/) by **rajaniesh kaushikk** has given detail information

Comment: The pipeline is not valid. Job Job_1: Step Docker input containerRegistry expects a service connection of type dockerregistry but the provided service connection sc-***dp is of type azurerm.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `repository` and `containerRegistry` value  in your `Docker@2` task, make sure they points to target resource. My script for your reference below. Please note the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) in `Docker@2` task, no `azureContainerRegistry` and `command` needed.

```
variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: acrconn1
  imageRepository: 'acrlearn'
  containerRegistry: 'test.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

[image]